# Azure Pipeline (DotNetCoreCLI@2) include DLL into nuget

Tags: c#, azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, nuget-package

In the process of upgrading a codebase/pipelines to Dotnet Core.
A project has some c++ code in a `oldcode.dll` file that it needs to be included.

Our old 'pack' pipeline looks something like:

```
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/ProjectName.csproj'
    buildProperties: '-IncludeReferencedProjects'
```

That generated a nuget with the following folder structure:

```
>build
--->oldcode.dll
--->project.targets

>lib
--->net472
------>project.dll
------>project.pdb
------>project.xml
```

Upgrading the project to Dotnetcore and using this pipeline does not include the `oldcode.dll` into the nuget

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/ProjectName.csproj'
```

I have read about the missing `IncludeReferencedProjects` function in DotNetCore
https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/3891

What is the simplest workaround for this case?
Could I somehow copy the `oldcode.dll` into the nuget before going to `push`?

UPDATE----
I have tried this:

- Setting the .nuspec directly into packagesToPack  didnt work.

and gives an error:

```
task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
inputs:
command: 'custom'
custom: 'pack **/NameOfFile.nuspec'


##[error]Error: The process 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe' failed with exit code 1
```

Is it the path i'm doing wrong?

This might be what I need to do, if I can figure out how to get the paths done right
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#packing-using-a-nuspec

```
dotnet pack <path to .csproj file> -p:NuspecFile=<path to nuspec file> -p:NuspecProperties=<> -p:NuspecBasePath=<Base path>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a `.nuspec` package with dotnet core even if you generally don't need to.

So create a file manually, include a `<file>` element and call pack on that rather than the project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
    <!-- Required elements-->
    <id></id>
    <version></version>
    <description></description>
    <authors></authors>

    <!-- Optional elements -->
    <!-- ... -->
    </metadata>
    <!-- Optional 'files' node -->
    <files>
        <file src="oldcode.dll" target="lib" />
    </files>
</package>
```

You may be able to sub the `.nuspec.` file for the `csproj` file in the `packagesToPack` argument, but if not, you can use a custom argument.

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'pack path/to/Myproject.nuspec'
```

Paths should be relative to the repository root, so

```
Root
|
|__MySolutionFolder
   |
   |__MyProject
      |
      |__ProjectName.csproj
      |__ProjectName.nuspec
```

Should be a relative path of ./MySolutionFolder/MyProject/ProjectName.nuspec

IIRC using forward slashes is always safe, but backwards slashes only work on Windows agents

Comment: Thanks for you reply!
setting the .nuspec. in the packagesToPack argument didnt work.

Comment: The custom argument might just be because I dont understand to get the right path - see my attempt above in the edit

Comment: Looking [at the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-pack) it seems as though pack doesn't support wildcards. A relative path should work though.

Comment: Could you help me how the path should look? Im trying but it gives the same error everytime